# influxdb + grafana with multiple counters

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have data stored in a table which has a timestamp, counters for various things, and tags of `[ receivingHostname, clientHostname, clientName, sourceType ]`.

I want to plot counters by various combinations of these tags, to select different groupings of the data.  For instance, I want to plot all counters for queries per second for `clientName` over a 1 hour time window.

So far, this seems to be very hard to do with InfluxDB.  I have tried `derivative(sum(counter), 60s)` or the like, but this produces garbage.

Other than massaging the data ahead of time and converting these counters to deltas, is there a way to do this?